# Userscript works in Firefox + Greasemonkey, not on Chrome + Tampermonkey or just plain Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts

I have written a script that works perfectly in Firefox. But whenever I use it in Chrome, it doesn't do anything. It gives me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: uneval is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

```
function inject(func) {
    window.location = 'javascript:(' + encodeURIComponent(uneval(func)) + ')();';
}

inject(function() {
    var alt = window.alert;
    window.alert = function(s) {
        if (!String(s).match(/Error: unable to connect to API/)) {
            alt.apply(window, arguments);
        }
    };

    // Ping the Angel server every five minutes
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (window.ANGEL && ANGEL.sessionTimer) {
            ANGEL.sessionTimer.reset();
            ANGEL.sessionTimer.extendSession();
        }
        window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 5 * 60 * 1000);
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MND documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/uneval#Browser_compatibility) `uneval()` is ONLY supported on Firefox.

> How do I fix this?

I suggest you to use [`Function.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) instead.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that uneval() was firefox only, but I couldn't find a function that worked the same way.